# generating random numbers for array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I have a problem in generating binary random numbers in C++. I want to  make an array and each element contain random numbers in binary form. And I want to XOR elements together. This is my code

```
void Msg::setXOR(double Code)
{
  int array[30];
  srand ( time(0) );
  for(int j = 0;j<30;j++)
  {
    i = rand();         
    array[j]=i
    double x = array[j]^ array[j+1]^ array[J+2];
    code = x ;
    this -> code_var = code
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and it doesn't make binary random numbers. Can anyone help me how should I fix it?

Comment: You *do* generate 30 random numbers, but you don't save them in the array.

Comment: Indent and format your code properly. You'll see why it doesn't work. (hint: curly brackets)

Comment: That code won't even compile as-is. Show us the real code instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i don't know how can i save them in the array. do you have any reference for learning?

Comment: all statements following the for loop are not in the loop, use curly braces.

Comment: @Biffen in answer part you can see it

Comment: @Zchen Are `i` and `J` members of `Msg`?

Comment: @Biffen no they are not... in .cc file i defined set and get method. i just used J and I in set method to define array.

Comment: @Zchen `i` and `J` (upper case) aren't declared in the code you've shown. Are they declared somewhere else or does your code not compile?

Comment: @Biffen i added a type ( double) before 'i' and it compiled. thanks for your kind help. and now i  just want to limit the random number to 10 digits.

Comment: @Zchen It should be of type `int` since you're putting it in an `int` array. And what about `J`? May I suggest turning on all warnings in your compiler?

Comment: @Biffen Yes you're right. I work with omnet++4.6 . I had turned it on. I just used J to define the size of array in FOR loop. Now i just don't have any clue to limit the size of random number in 10 digits

Comment: @Zchen No, you use `j` for the for loop. `j` is not the same as `J`. As for limiting the digits I gave you a clue in an other comment. Perhaps it's time for a new question?

Comment: @Biffen Oh i See, I had changed it to 'j' in my codes. Yes i guess i have to ask a new question. Thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;
auto generatef = std::bind(distribution,generator);
std::array<int,30> array;
std::generate(array.begin(), array.end(), generatef);
double x = std::accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 0, std::bit_xor<>);
```

Comment: Thanks . i'm noob in programming :( does it make binary random number?

Comment: Yes, using <random> is the new way of generating random numbers in C++11

Comment: Thanks alot. and how can i change the size of these binary random numbers? for example i want 10 digit random numbers

Comment: @Zchen They're just numbers, they have no base, i.e. they're neither binary, decimal nor octal, etc. If you want to have a certain number of digits when *representing* the numbers in binary form, just work out the highest number that has no more than ten binary digits and make sure the random numbers aren't larger than that.

Comment: @Biffen  thanks for your help :) actually for now i have no idea how to set the highest random number in 10 digits

Comment: @Z chen The highest  number with 10 digits is 9999999999 so use `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0,9999999999}`

Comment: By the way 9,999,999,999 is greter than 2,147,483,647 which is the greatest number for an signed 32 bit int, so you probably have to choose another type, perhaps `long long` or `unsigned long long`

Answer (score 0):

you did not store the generated random num in the array.

```
int array[30];
srand ( time(0) );
int x=0;
for (int j = 0;j<30;j++)
{
   array[j]=rand();
   x ^= array[j];
}
return x;
```

Comment: I just need binary. how can i change it to binary from ? Thanks.